# select all checkboxes command jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all of my checkboxes to be checked when clicking a link

looks like this: `<a href='javascript:;' onclick="$.overall.selectAll();">select all</a>`

inputs in a loop:  `<input type="checkbox" name="delete[$i]" value="1" />`

jquery code:

```
var checked_status = this.checked;

    $("input[name=delete]").each(function() {
    this.checked = checked_status;
});
```

Can someone help me get it to check all.. ?

When clicking at the select all link, nothing seems to happen.. (not even an error)

Comment: can you remove the onclick attribute of the element. Also if you paste your markup and ensure it validates at w3c.

Comment: You are missing `=` after `input type` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following.

Updated. The handler is tied to an anchor therefore there will be no this.checked attribute available.

```
$("#select_all").click(function(){
    $("input[name^=delete]").attr('checked',  'checked');  
});
```

Comment: no reaction, not even an error :-/ & and i have included my js file.. :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Tutorial: [Select All Checkbox](http://jetlogs.org/jquery/jquery_select_all.html)

Comment: thaks, i'm familiar with the link you added. 

I just want it to be link, and not a checkbox to check them all

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the `[name^=delete]` selector ("starts with"), since your checkboxes names aren't *exactly* "delete", they're "delete[X]' for some number X.