# Button to select all checkboxes within a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select all checkboxes command jquery, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271097/select-all-checkboxes-command-jquery-javascript)

I am having trouble selecting all checkboxes in a div with jquery. This is the code that I currently have for the function

```
function selectAllCheckBoxes() {
        $('#additionalrecords input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean *selecting* in the sense that the wrong elements are chosen or that their state is not changed? [Either way, it seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/mm3RC/). The selector by itself is correct, maybe your HTML is different but as you didn't post it we cannot say anything about it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Debug your selector `console.log($('#additionalrecords input[type="checkbox"]'))`.

Comment: I want to mark all checkboxes as checked.

Comment: Ok, then there is nothing wrong with the code you posted. If you don't provide more information, we cannot help you. Voting to close...

Comment: @BWoods, can you post the relevant parts of your markup, especially the `additionalRecords` `<div>` element?

Comment: It works with just this line but using .attr('checked', true) works as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On jQuery 1.6 and higher, try using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("#additionalrecords input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: You are right, but I don't think this will solve the problem.

Comment: @Felix, I think so too, but I cannot help more without seeing the questioner's markup.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$('#additionalrecords input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: attr('checked', 'checked') is the right way to mark a checkbox.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I checked jquery FAQ. Both ways are right.

Comment: `.attr` is not the right way for anything, especially for marking a checkbox [:'(](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/004/006/y-u-no-guy.jpg)

Comment: it could be not the best way, but it's a valid way

Answer (score 1):

use 
    $("#additionalrecords input:checkbox").attr("checked", true);

And here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/akuzus/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting 'checked' attr to 'checked' try true

```
$('#additionalrecords input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djgraff209/mqk8L/